# Float element inside inline text

Tags: html, css

I have following code:

```
<div>
  <div id="dynamic" style="float:left;height:50px;background-color:#aaa;">
    floated block which will be dynamically increase
  </div>
  <div id="static" style="height:50px;background-color:#FC3;">
    Hello guys
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to move `static` div as `dynamic` div width changes. Above code works as I want but I don't know whether the above way is the right to do that?

Is floated div inside inline text the right way? Is that cross-browser?

Will this code affect anything else, like the content below it or moving below `static` div?

And why does floated div not move below inline content, rather aligns it with inline text?

Comment: Unsure really what you are asking - floating a div within a div, that is fine, and will look the same on all browsers.

Comment: Floating an element removes it from the page flow, so it will no align with the text

Answer (score 1):

You can use `float:left` for the `<div id="static">` too. I don't see any issues until your dynamic div width + static div width reach the window width.

This >> http://jsfiddle.net/gxpBL/  is what I'm telling.